# content filter (add_filter) for category description?

Tags: theme-development, filters

I'm running an add_filter function on the_content and I need to run the same function on the category description.

Does something like that exist or do I need to create a custom function for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, hook it right onto `category_description`.

Here's an example:

```
function category_desc_filter( $desc, $cat_id ) {
    $desc = 'Description: ' . $desc;
    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'category_description', 'category_desc_filter' );
```

Didn't test it but based on the Codex it should work.

See the Codex for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Category_and_Term_Filters